# css absolute element hid by overflow: auto

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, css-position

When I hover the link, an `absolute pseudo element` will show.

I make the div `overflow-y: scroll`, those `pseudo element` outside view can't show, they were still using the position without `scroll` getting computed.

Chrome has that problem, Firefox works well.

Here are two images:

- [Chrome](http://123.56.154.187:8090/config/c-index/b536f378-ecf1-fd51-b1f2-bd79da006987.png)
- [Firefox](http://123.56.154.187:8090/config/c-index/0d364c0c-bdae-0bac-56d5-574720931686.png)

```css
    
.blog .widget-panel {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: fixed;
}

.blog .widget-panel > div {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block {
    display: block;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 7px;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block:hover,
.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block.selected {
    background-color: #38B7EA;
    color: #fff;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box.block .tag-block[data-title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(85,85,85, 0.9);
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 2.8em;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block .count{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog">
    <div class="panel panel-default widget-panel">
        <div class="tag-box block">
           
            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
            All
            <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
                <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                    test
                    <span class="count">7</span>
                </a>            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
                <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                    test
                    <span class="count">7</span>
                </a>            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
                <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                    test
                    <span class="count">7</span>
                </a>            <a class="tag-block" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                All
                <span class="count">14</span>
            </a>
            <a class="tag-block tag-test" href="#" data-title="A few languages with well-developed systems of articles may distinguish additional subtypes. Within each type, languages may have various forms of each article">
                test
                <span class="count">7</span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use same ID again and again in a single web page e.g. ```all-tags```. If you are setting ```position: absolute``` to any div or tag and want to show it with respect to the parent tag then you should set ```position: relative``` to the parent tag.

Comment: Thanks. When I add the `position: relative` to the parent (`.tag-block`),  it will show a horizontal scrollbar, not showing like I want, too.

Comment: When adding `position: relative;` to `.tag-block` will make titles hidden by `overflow`.
like here: [https://jsfiddle.net/dp70zv5o/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/dp70zv5o/2/.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheBigDMo1/k2ahruyb/5/

Use CSS tooltips : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp 
    
     - If you use this option you need to get rid of the `data-title` attribute altogether

Here is your CSS:

```
    .blog .widget-panel {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: fixed;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box.remove-over-flow {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block {
    display: block;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 7px;
    color: #777;
    background-color: #fff;

    position: relative;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block .tooltip-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 1;

    white-space: nowrap;

    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: fixed;
}

.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block .tooltip-text::after {
    content: " ";
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;

    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
}


.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block:hover .tooltip-text,
.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block.selected .tooltip-text {  
    visibility: visible;
    /*background-color: #38B7EA;*/
    /*color: #fff;*/
}
```

Here is your jQuery:

```
$(".tag-block").on('click', function () {
    $(".tag-box").toggleClass("remove-over-flow");
});

$('.tooltip-text').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

edited: added working Fiddle, added CSS

Comment: Thanks, that is browser default tooltip. I can't style it. Using the `data-title` is same to your `CSS tooltips` :)  I can't add a `position:relative` to the link.

Comment: Your tooltip itself should be a `span` that is made visible (using relative positioning) with tag-block:hover instead of an HTML attribute of your anchor tag. 

Your tooltip span should read like this: `<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>`

Comment: You should also have a `tag-block:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}` in your CSS file.

That way you can style your tooltip with `.tagblock .tooltiptext {     visibility: hidden; }` in CSS.

Comment: hi, I have tried this. please see here [https://jsfiddle.net/dp70zv5o/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/dp70zv5o/2/).When I do this, the `tooltip` will also hide by `.tag-block`'s `overflow`( like add `position: relative;` to `.tag-block` when using `data-title`).

Comment: set `position: fixed` on tooltip-text

Comment: `.blog .widget-panel .tag-box .tag-block .tooltip-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 999;

    white-space: nowrap;

    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: fixed;
}`

Comment: You can also set the CSS `opacity: .8` to give it the same look as `data-title`

Comment: I just updated the Fiddle. I set the CSS file in my answer. This is my first time using Fiddle.

Comment: What's wrong with it? The tooltip was being cut off by the `tag-box` at first, now it isn't being cut off anymore. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: hi, scroll to the bottom then see the links.

Comment: Yes, but see the last few links: [image](http://123.56.154.187:8090/config/c-index/044ec61e-7e5d-ee06-99a9-bb6d66daf923.png)

Comment: If you want to take away the tooltip once that link is clicked, you're probably going to have to do that with jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Wait, I see what you mean. Try playing around with the positioning.

Comment: Your span tag is going to have to be "un-nested" from your block. It's going to be treated like overflow every time. Maybe create another div to the right of the tag-box and set it to `left: -20px;`

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for but this is the best I have gotten so far: https://jsfiddle.net/TheBigDMo1/k2ahruyb/2/

Comment: Really thanks, I'm trying to use JavaScript, too.Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome and it's working fine for me. Looks just like your Firefox example.

[ I put this as an answer because I do not know how to comment with images ]

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: hi, please scroll the scrollbar and see the last few links.